# using tempdata to share data between partial view and main view

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

Basiacly I have 1 view with a menu at the top in a header, a main content div and a sidebar div, all buttons import a different partialview into a main content div, now i wish to only import the sidebar if its different to the one currently loaded (saves on load time)

```
@{if (TempData["CurrentSideBar"] != "Standard") 
  {
      <script type="text/javascript">
      $('#sidebarmain').load('@Url.Action("Standard", "SideBar")', function () {
           $('#loadingAjaxs').hide(); $('#flubestext').show(); window.history.pushState(null, 'title', '/users/');
      })
      </script>
      TempData["CurrentSideBar"] = "Standard";
   }}
```

Ive tried this and viewbag and it doesnt work, this is at the top of each main partialview which goes into the content div from the header buttons. Hope this makes sense

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you have something like this (if it involves button to change a partialview/html):

you can make a link/button and call an action and if there's an html result then replace the view or if not the don't replace

ControllerAction in .cs

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
public JsonResult ControllerAction()
        {
            string newPartialHtml = "";
            using (var sw = new StringWriter())
            {
                ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, "NewPartialViewToLoad");
                var viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View, ViewData,TempData, sw);
                viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
                newPartialHtml= sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
            }
            return Json(new{ doReplace=true, newHtml = newPartialHtml});
        }
```

hope it helps

edit: but of course if you do this a lot, i suggest to put this into a static method for converting partialview to string

Answer (score 0):

Add a Javascript variable in your main view :

```
_standard = 0;
```

In the standard sidebar add this :

```
_standard = 1;
```

Now change this code :

```
    @{if (TempData["CurrentSideBar"] != "Standard") 
    {
      <script type="text/javascript">
      $('#sidebarmain').load('@Url.Action("Standard", "SideBar")', function () {
           $('#loadingAjaxs').hide(); $('#flubestext').show(); window.history.pushState(null, 'title', '/users/');
      })
      </script>
      TempData["CurrentSideBar"] = "Standard";
   }}
```

by this one :

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      if(_standard == 0){
         $('#sidebarmain').load('@Url.Action("Standard", "SideBar")', function () {
            $('#loadingAjaxs').hide(); $('#flubestext').show(); window.history.pushState(null,   'title', '/users/');
         })
         _standard = 1;
      }
    });
  </script>
```